# Why does bpl has Error Loading a resource string after upgrade?

Tags: devexpress, c++builder

We have a bpl that has some resource (.rc) files which has strings in it. It is defined via `STRINGTABLE` and loaded via a `LoadStr()` call. The project was in version 10.1 Berlin. We upgraded to the latest 11.1 Alexandria and now the call returns `NULL`. So to test I added the line at the main

```
extern "C" int _libmain(unsigned long reason)
{
  String str = LoadStr(231); **// Works**
  return 1;
}
```

but the existing code below does not work.

```
**.h**
PACKAGE String __fastcall GetValueSetDesc(int ACount);

**.cpp**
String __fastcall GetValueSetDesc(int ACount)
{
  String ValueDesc = LoadStr(ACount); **// Does not work, retuns NULL**
  return ValueDesc;
}
```

I tried creating the project from scratch (and adding files to it). Any one has experienced this issue or know what to try?

Comment: Did you verify that your `STRINGTABLE` resource is actually present in your `BPL` file after the upgrade?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, the rc file is in the project and is built. My test LoadStr(231) works (within the bpl), but the actual call GetValueSetDesc() does not. That is the weird part.

Comment: Where is `GetValueSetDesc()` being called from, exactly? In the BPL or in the EXE? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @RemyLebeau ```GetValueSetDesc()``` is called from a static lib, which is in-turn called from an exe. This is a part of a complex project and outside this environment, this issue is not reproducible. There seems to be something incompatible with the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with DevExpress components. The call was from a DevExpress change event. A call from a non DevExpress component worked fine. The way I solved this is to re-create the cbproj from scratch and add the files, settings etc (in the exe, the bpl seems fine). Man, DevExpress gave me a lot of grief this time around when we upgraded!